# Connecting To Microsoft SQL Server Using TCL

Tags: sql-server, tcl

Is there any package that enables TCL to query MS SQL Server?

I have searched and found the following interfaces or packages:

http://www.parand.com/tcl-sql/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl-sql/

http://www.sqlite.org

If there is no such module available, can you provide me with an efficient way to fetch a query result from MS SQL Server?

Comment: I think the subject should be changed to read "Microsoft SQL Server" instead. An "SQL server" is a term pertaining to technolog while the OP referred to a specific piece of software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MS SQL Server](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6193) wiki page lists a few options:

- [TclODBC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclodbc/)
- [TclSQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclsql/)
- [TDBC](http://tdbc.tcl.tk/index.cgi/index)

They all have various requirements, and don't all work cross-platform, but hopefully you'll find one that fits your needs.

Comment: I should add that I even use Tcl to access an instance of MS SQL Server from a Linux machine using TclODBC and FreeTDS as a backend.

Comment: If you're using TDBC, you'll want the `tdbc::odbc` package too, which is a connector to ODBC (and which should be well-supported; it's a key use-case for TDBC).