# Connecting To Microsoft SQL Server Using TCL over IVR

Tags: sql-server, odbc, tcl, ivr

Regarding previous question [on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464052/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-tcl) I have gone for installing the tclodbc on my ubuntu client. Installing such package requires access to ODBC which is located in iODBC package. I am testing these requirements to have the solution in hand and apply these in a voice gateway AS535XN. However, I doubt that such commands to configure and install these packages, are available on that device. Since I don't have any test server, I must test it in a production server which is a great risk.

My question is: Am I on the right way to connect to a MS SQL database from that voice gateway? if so, is it possible to configure and install the required packages on that server?
As fetching Credit Card amount requires Radius server, Do I still need such a server?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes I need a radius server and I must configure it to provide correct AVPairs to the TCL code.